# Запуск service из $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'....)

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Эксперементирую с ui.router.

Я работаю с эти примером http://habrahabr.ru/post/245049/

Пишу сервис

```
angular.module('myApp.auth')
  .service('SessionService', [
    '$injector',
    function($injector) {
      "use strict";

      this.checkAccess = function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        var $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope'),
            $sessionStorage = $injector.get('$sessionStorage');

        if (toState.data !== undefined) {
          if (toState.data.noLogin !== undefined && toState.data.noLogin) {
            // если нужно, выполняйте здесь какие-то действия 
            // перед входом без авторизации
          }
        } else {
          // вход с авторизацией
          if ($sessionStorage.user) {
            $scope.$root.user = $sessionStorage.user;
          } else {
            // если пользователь не авторизован - отправляем на страницу авторизации
            event.preventDefault();
            $scope.$state.go('auth.login');
          }
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Затем пытаюсь его обработать:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'myApp.auth',
  'ui.router',
  'ngStorage'
])

.run([
  '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'SessionService',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, SessionService) {

    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

    $rootScope.user = null;

    // Здесь мы будем проверять авторизацию
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
      function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        SessionService.checkAccess(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams);
      }
    );
  }
])
```

Но в итоге получаю внутри `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart')` получаю `TypeError: SessionService.checkAccess is not a function`

В чем может быть проблема? Покажите, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, на примере примитивный `.service (hello world)` и запуск его в `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart')`

Comment: можете воспроизвести вашу ошибку на [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)?

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, я просто запихнул его внутри сервиса

```
 service.prototype.testrole = function () {
            console.log('Проверка роли');
            var url = '';
            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {
                    url = $location.url();
                    if (
                        (url.indexOf('editquests') == 1) ||
                        (url.indexOf('editprojects') == 1)

                    ) {
                        if (this.usersession) {
                            if (this.usersession.role_id != 2) {
                                $location.path('/home');
                                console.log('У вас не достаточно прав');
                            }
                        } else {
                            $location.path('/home');
                            console.log('У вас не достаточно прав');
                        }
                    }
                }.bind(this)
            );
            url = $location.url();
            if (
                (url.indexOf('editquests') == 1) ||
                (url.indexOf('editprojects') == 1)
            ) {
                if (this.usersession) {
                    if (this.usersession.role_id != 2) {
                        $location.path('/home');
                        console.log('У вас не достаточно прав');
                    }
                } else {
                    $location.path('/home');
                    console.log('У вас не достаточно прав');
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: плохое решение, при каждом вызове _testrole_ будет добавляться обработчик: `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',`

Comment: @Grundy  а как лучше тогда сделать, отслеживание перехода

Comment: В оригинальном посте все правильно было сделано, скорее всего ошибка где-то еще

Comment: @Grundy а ну так у меня так же в run вызов идет testrole

Comment: а так же он еще где угодно может быть вызван